# Excel cell, circular reference problems

Tags: excel

I am new to Excel.  I am making a spreadsheet for a product list. I want a priced cell to adjust when a quantity cell is changed, but I keep getting a circular reference error.

For example `CELL A1` is the amount of the product and cell `D1` is the quantity. When I change `D1` I want `A1` to multiply by `this`.

Comment: What is the formula in A1

Comment: You cannot have a formula like this `=A1*D1` in A1 without circular reference.  Put the value per in a different cell then refer to that cell `=B1*D1` in A1.